# RGeo: proj4 not supported error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rgeo

I am new to working with geospatial datam and am working with the Rails [RGeo gem](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo). I am getting the following error in my rails console:

```
> geo_shape = ES_Zone::FACTORY.parse_wkt
RGeo::Error::UnsupportedOperation: Proj4 is not supported because the proj4 library was not found at install time.
```

When I test to see if proj4 is supported, it predictably comes back as false.

```
> RGeo::CoordSys::Proj4.supported?
=> false
```

I googled the error message, but I cannot find any resources for this particular problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you have the Proj4 library installed when you installed the RGeo gem?  If so, which directory was it in?

Comment: I did not know that this existed as a separate library until I got this error message. Is this the library that you mean? http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error says, the [Proj4 library](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) was not installed during installation of the RGeo gem.

By default RGeo expects the Proj4 library to be in one of the following directories:

```
/usr/local
/usr/local/proj
/usr/local/proj4
/opt/local
/opt/proj
/opt/proj4
/opt
/usr
/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix
```

If you install it somewhere else you need to install the RGeo gem with the option `--with-proj-dir=/path/to/proj4/directory`.

I suggest you `gem uninstall rgeo`, install `Proj4` to one of the default directories and then `gem install rgeo` again.

You can find the error message you received at the top of the `projected_factory` method of `lib/rgeo/geographic/interface.rb`.  `RGeo::CoordSys::Proj4.supported?` in turn looks for the presence of a `_create` method.  This is defined by a `C` routine based on the installation of the `Proj4` library, which is why the library needs to be present during installation of the gem and can't just be added later.

Comment: There's [a few other places this looks now](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/blob/master/ext/geos_c_impl/extconf.rb) including `/usr/lib64`.